# How to make the facebox cover only a given div, as opposed to covering the entire body?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, facebox

I would like the facebox overlay to cover only a given part div, not the entire screen.

I changed "body" in facebox.js, but nothing changes

```
  $("body").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"></div>')
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#facebox_overlay` is position absolute, which will not recognize static parent position. If you position your container `relative`, or `absolute` - it should then only fill the container.

```
$("#divId").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide" />');
```

CSS:

```
#divId { position: relative; }
```

Comment: hmmm, to make it work, i would need to change the overlay from fixed to absolute. is that ok?

Comment: fixed can be positioned within relative also, so no, this is not necessary. Unless you container has overflow however, the fixed position is useless imo.

Comment: i can believe that, there are lots of random differences in css that i really do not know what it is for. =)